# How to synchronously update mapbox gl style?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, synchronous

**Context:**
I have an application that steps through an array that contains arrays of feature IDs that I want to style every 100ms or when a user clicks a back/forward button. My current implementation uses a custom event listener where I update the index of the outer array to get a new set of features. I start by using removeFeatureState() to clear the feature states and then for each of the feature ids in the new inner array I use setFeatureState() to control the styling.

**Code:**

```
document.addEventListener('update', function (e) {
            var algo_step = run_data[run_index];
            map.removeFeatureState(
                {source: 'precincts'});

            if (algo_step.feasible){
                let district_ix = 0;
                for(center in algo_step.partition){
                    algo_step.partition[center].forEach(precinct =>
                        map.setFeatureState(
                            { source: 'precincts', id: precinct },
                            { district_n : district_ix }
                        ));
                    district_ix++;
                }
            }
            else{
                algo_step.area.forEach(precinct =>
                    map.setFeatureState(
                        { source: 'precincts', id: precinct },
                        { infeasible : true }
                    ));
            }
        }, false);
```

**Problem:** When I run the application the styling sometimes does not update correctly. My current understanding is that this is because of asynchronous updates to the feature state not happening before the map is rendered but I am not positive.

Expected Behavior
[image: Expected Behavior]
(sometimes) Observed Behavior
[image: (sometimes) Observed Behavior]

Therefore I think that I can solve this problem if I can update the map synchronously and/or at the end of the event listener render the map with all of the feature-states updated. Based on https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/7893 it is not clear if this is currently implemented.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to say without seeing it in action, but it sounds like some kind of race condition that happens when your update function sometimes takes more than 100ms?

One thing you could try is waiting for the `idle` event, and skipping updates occasionally.

Something like this:

```js
let idle = true;
map.on('idle', {
  idle = true;
});
window.setInterval(() => {
  if (!idle) {
    return; // still processing something, let's skip
  }
  idle = false;
  var algo_step = run_data[run_index];
  // ... rest of update function
}, 100);
```

Comment: So it isn't actually just 100ms. I have a slider to change that interval as well as "back" and "forward" buttons to step through run_data manually. The malupdate happens regardless of what speed you choose (and almost always looks the exact same). Curiously, sometimes stepping forward to an index produces a different result than stepping back to it.